# Eloquent update and get record back

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When I usually update a record, I do

```
$myObject->update(['field' => 'value']);
```

And that updates both the database and my instance $myObject. However, sometimes, I need to do bulk updates, so I use the model facade and do

```
$result = MyObject::where(...)->update(['field' => 'value');
```

The issue here is that $result sends me back a boolean instead of the updated instances so what I usually have to do separately is right after I need to do the same filter, but this time a get().

```
$objects = MyObject::where(...)->get();
```

Is there a more efficient way to update and get the records in one call/request to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO your way is arguably the most efficient with Eloquent.

If you care about performance more than using Eloquent then with raw queries in PostgreSQL (with `RETURNING` clause) or SQL Server (with `OUTPUT` clause) you can return updated records in one go.

MySQL unfortunately doesn't have such support on a statement level.

In all supported by Laravel databases you can also achieve this (one trip to the database) also with a stored procedure.

Answer (score 12):

This will solve the problem

```
$product = Product::where('id','76887')->first();

$result = $product->update(['field' => 'value');

$theUpdatedData = $product->refresh(); 

return $theUpdatedData //This return the updated record
```

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way to archive is.**

```
$object = Model::find(1);

$object->field_name_to_update = 'new_value';
$object->another_field_name_to_update = 'new_value2';

$object->save();

echo $object->field_name_to_update; # has updated value
echo $object->another_field_name_to_update; # has updated value
```

> Make sure fields are in `$fillable` in the model to avoid [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) error

Answer (score 0):

you can use inside query

like this:

```
$messages = MessageGroup::where(function(Builder $query) use($request,$checkCountUser)
           {
            $query->whereRaw('((message_group_from_id="'.$request->student_id.'" 
            AND message_from_type = "students" 
            AND  message_group_to_id IN('.implode(',',$checkCountUser).') 
            AND message_to_type = "users") OR (message_group_to_id="'.$request->student_id.'" 
            AND message_to_type = "students" 
            AND  message_group_from_id IN('.implode(',',$checkCountUser).') 
            AND message_from_type = "users"))')->update(['message_is_read' => 1,'message_is_delivered' => 1]);
           //$query;
            return $query;
        })->get();
```

if you see this

Comment: Hi, please review your formatting. This is very difficult to read/understand

Answer (score -1):

If you want the most efficient method possible, you can update the database with the single update command, and then loop through your $objects in memory with a `foreach` loop and set each `$object->field = 'value'`.  It isn't especially elegant, but that would be the most efficient way to do it in terms of speed since that way you don't need to re-fetch the models from the database.

```
$result = MyObject::where(...)->update(['field' => 'value');

foreach ($objects as $object) {
   $object->field = 'value';
}
```